# Javascript injecting html at runtime css height not stretching

Tags: javascript, css

I am injecting html at runtime into my page:

```
document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="'+pageUrl+'"></object>';
```

The data injected happens to have a scrollbar and not stretching 100%...so I've added this:

```
document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="'+pageUrl+'" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></object>';
```

This fixes the width issues and makes the content 100% width but the height has a scrollbar and I don't want it to scroll, I need it to stretch.

I've also tried **height:auto;** but it's not stretching.

How can I get it to stretch to the whole height?

Answer (score 1):

For the 100% height to work, every parent element (including html and body tag) needs to have a defined height of 100%.

Comment: I know that, and it's why I'm not using it

Comment: may I know why not? 

Only other way to do it is to calculate the height with JS and set a fixed height.

Comment: The reason I don't want to go that route is that I want to get injecting code on other div's too, and I don't have to have to add css: height:100% to every div's on my webpage. Calculating the height in js and setting a fixed height, sound's promising